# Image from SQL Server 2019 in Crystal Reports not showing

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to get the image (I tried `image` type and `varbinary(max)`) from SQL Server to show up in Crystal Reports. I am using a stored procedure to get all column values to display into Crystal Reports, and all data is displaying fine except the image.

> image from vb.net to sql

```
  imgQR.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            ImageBytes = ms.ToArray()
```

Comment: Definitely use `varbinary(max)` as `image` is depreciated. Are you sure that the image has been successfully stored in the database?

Comment: Along the same lines as Dale, if it is being saved correctly are you able to verify that you're retrieving it correctly?  Maybe show both the saving and query code

Comment: thank u for replay , yes its saved and get value but s not showing in crystal report